# Huawei Devices' Emulator Hardware Profile files for Android Studio AVD Manager

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I know that Huawei has an *online* "**cloud debug**" option to test mobile application on Huawei devices.However I could not find any Hardware Profile files of Huawei devices on anywhere.

It would be good to have an opportunity to do *offline* mobile application test using Android Studio Huawei Device Emulator.

Do you know any platform or website for Huawei Emulator Hardware Profile files that we can download  and import to Android Studio AVD Manager?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are no emulators for Huawei devices yet. In one of the Huawei Developer Day conferences the lecturer said that they are working on an emulator but it is not an easy task to create an EMUI emulator. Hence there is also not an actual release frame for it.

The choice of devices you can use over Cloud Debugging are real devices in one of Huawei's labs located in each specific country. They have special software to allow the usage over cloud services and erase all data after a user has finished his tests.

For convenience you can also use the latest version of the [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/) in order to access Cloud Debugging directly from you IDE.